# User based menu control in PHP - Menu mapping with User

Tags: php, mysql, menu, menuitem

I'm looking for controlling menu based on user role. I have successfully created a database mapping for menu control.
I don't have an idea of mapping the user based menu control.
Is there any code available so that I can customize based on my need. Or any sample snippet.
Also, the main thing is - each user should be checked at top of each page whether they have rights to the page to access.
If someone gets the direct url link and if they try to access it they should be redirected to error page.

I'm breaking my head, and since I'm new to development I don't know the exact keyword to search the code.

Anyhelp will be of great help. The menu level looks like this

```
    menu_master
    ===========

    m_id    menu_name   parent  link
    1       M1          0       #
    2       M2          0       #
    3       M1.M1       1       m1.php
    4       M2.M2       2       m2.php

    user_master
    ===========

    u_id    user_name Dept  
    1       ABC       D1
    2       DEF       D2

    user_menu_mapping
    =================

    um_id       m_id        u_id
    1           1,2         1
    2           1,3         2
```

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading some tutorials on creating basic authentication systems using a database and session cookies like [this one](http://www.sourcecodetuts.com/php/27/how-create-login-page-php-and-mysql-session).. It's pretty straight forward. After setting up such a system, you can easily extend it to also get the appropriate menu et cetera.

Comment: FYI - i have done the login pages, and basic login functions and it works perfect. now mapping matters !!! :( and i'm worried. i use login function and on successful login, i was able to set the session for each user_id and redirect them to welcome.php page

Answer (score -1):

I 'm using Zend Framework, solution is simple

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.navigation.pages.html#zend.navigation.pages.common

Comment: i'm not using any framework, apart from that, any other core php code for my query? help me please

Comment: Are you really recommending zend to a beginner? Sure it's a great framework, but definitely overkill for such a thing!